# datacharts in reportlab

Tags: django, reportlab

I am getting this error which running reportlab with django:
Error was: No module named datacharts

When I checked the
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\rlextra\graphics\guiedit folder I dont find datacharts.py but I only find datacharts.pyc and datacharts.pyo
For all other files, even py is there. I tried downloading rlextra again but py for datacharts is still not there.
Is this the right format or I am missing on anything which django is not able to find.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through the [Reportlab installation instructions](http://www.reportlab.com/software/installation/)?

In particular, step 3 tells you how to test your rlextra installation, and step 4 mentions that you will need to install [Python Windows extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) in order to use data-aware charts with a database.